# Indicial Polynomial of $3z^2u''+\sin(z)u'-u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the roots of the indicial equation for $$3z^2u''+\sin(z)u'-u=0$$

My attempt:

$$z^2u''+\frac{\sin(z)}{3}u'-\frac{u}{3}=0$$

> What is $P_0(z)$ and $Q_0(z)$, such that $r(r-1)+P_0r+Q_0$ is the indicial polynomial?

I'm quite certain $Q_0=-\frac{1}{3}$.

I noticed that if $P_0=\frac{1}{3}$, that is if $P_0$ is the coefficient of $zu'$ in the expansion $\frac{\sin(z)}{3}u'$, then the answer comes out.

Comment: Indicial equation =differential equation?  What is an indicial polynomial?  Even if you say a "differential polynomial," I still never heard of it.

Comment: It generally of interest when using the Frobenius Method of solving ODEs. Here is a link, it may help with you understanding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method

Comment: It also appeas that you expect $u(z)=z^r$ to be a solution.  You can forget it.  With the $\sin(z)$ term, $z^r$ is not going to satisfy your equation.

Comment: I see.  You are trying to get a power series solution.  Then, use $\sin(z)\approx z$ for small $z$, show that, if $u(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\,A_k\,z^{k+r}$, then $$r(r-1)+\frac{1}{3}\,r-\frac13=0\,.$$  This should give $r=-\dfrac13$ and $r=1$.

Comment: The question also states "do not try to construct a series solution", which I guess implies there is another (easier?) way. Are you suggesting we construct a series solution?

Comment: Your question is to merely determine $r$, isn't it?  So, getting the power series would be beyond your question (and it is probably very difficult to find a power series solution completely, unless you are getting a few terms).  Hence, no, I am not suggesting that we construct the whole solution.  We need to only find $r$.

Comment: My main question is is $P_0=\frac{1}{3}$? Is this because it is the coefficient of $zu'$ in the expansion of $\frac{\sin(z)}{3}u'$? For instance, how did you know $r(r-1)+\frac{1}{3}r-\frac{1}{3}$ was the indicial equation?

Comment: Well, I got that coefficient from knowing that $$\frac{\sin(z)}{3}\approx \frac{1}{3}\,z$$ for small $z$.

Comment: Ok cool. Do you know if there is a more general way to derive this equation? For instance, if $\sin(z)=4z$ (or something like this).

Comment: Well, this doesn't make sense: $\sin(z)=4z$.  But you can use a similar method if, for example, the $\frac{\sin(z)}{3}$ coefficient of $u'$ is replaced by, say, $4\,\tan(5z)$.  Then, you have $$4\,\tan(5z)\approx 4\cdot 5z=20\,z$$ for small $z$.